# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Student'

Tags: sql, syntax

```
    public void SQLread()
    {
        sdr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }

    private void btnLOGIN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenCon();
        SqlCmd("select * Student where USN=@usn and Password=@pw");
        Parameters("@usn", txtUSER.Text);
        Parameters("@pw", txtPWD.Text);
        SQLread();
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
            frmMain mm = new frmMain();
            mm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username/Password");
        }

    }
```

I'm new to everything. I don't know why it keeps happening. Checked SQL if i misspelled anything but i don't think there's any problem.

The error happens here:
                       sdr=cmd.ExecuteReader();

tnks for yogesh sharma for the answer.
i forgot the \from\ in SqlCmd("select * Student where USN=@usn and Password=@pw"); -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `from` clause :

```
select s.* 
from Student s
where USN = @usn and Password = @pw
```